# object 'CexpandAltRep' not found

Tags: r, data.table

Two errors i've encountered recently:

```
Error in setDT(data) : object 'CexpandAltRep' not found
```

and

```
Error in setDT(list(indices = rep.int(indices__, len__),
irows = irows)) : object 'CexpandAltRep' not found
```

Do you have any clues how to solve that?

Comment: It would be very useful to add a small example of your data to know where that `error` is coming from.

Comment: Actually I've solved this issue by downgrading to data.table 1.10.4-3
No clue how this happened but definitely will investigate and let you know as soon as solution is found. 

PS. @Biocrazy it's a standard "data.table" "data.frame" dataset with 2 columns (numeric & caracter)

Comment: getting same error when running `caret::varImp(model)`

Comment: Also getting the error when running `data.table::test.data.table()` on r 3.4.3

Comment: @BigTimeStats which data.table version are you using? Generally updating to R >3.6.0 is recommendable